# Numpy multiply array with scalar translation to c#

Tags: python, c#, numpy, opencv

Basically I have this python code using **opencv** to find the contours in a given image. To improve contours recognition, I apply a resize to the original image and then I apply a ratio to the obtained contours to "translate" them to the real image size:

```
ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
image = imutils.resize(original, height = 500)
contours= cv2.findContours(image , cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour , True), True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        selectedContour = approx
        break

reshapedSelectedContour = selectedContour.reshape(4, 2) * ratio
#paint contours on original
```

This is working as expected. When I try to translate it to c# it's not working well:

```
double ratio = image.Height() / 500;
Imgproc.Resize(original, image, new Size((int)(image.Width() * 500 / (double)image.Height()), 500));
IList<MatOfPoint> contours = new JavaList<MatOfPoint>();
Imgproc.FindContours(image, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RetrList, Imgproc.ChainApproxSimple);

MatOfPoint2f selectedContour = new MatOfPoint2f();

foreach (MatOfPoint contour in contours)
{
    MatOfPoint2f approx = new MatOfPoint2f();
    Imgproc.ApproxPolyDP(new MatOfPoint2f(contour.ToArray()), approx, Imgproc.ArcLength(new MatOfPoint2f(contour.ToArray()), true) * 0.02, true);

    if (approx.Total() == 4)
    {
       selectedContour = approx;
       break;
    }
}

Mat reshapedSelectedContour = new Mat();
Core.Multiply(selectedContour.Reshape(4, 2), new Scalar(ratio), reshapedSelectedContour );
//Paint contours on original
```

If I paint the contours over **image** (the resized image) I get the same results for python and c#. But when I try to paint **reshapedSelectedContour** over the **original** image, python version is working and c# is not giving me the same output.

Is my way of obtaining **reshapedSelectedContour** in c# correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by manually obtaining the contour points and multiplying all them by the ratio